# samsung tablet GT- P3113 have OTG USB support?

Tags: usb, keyboard, samsung, usb-on-the-go

Does the samsung tablet model # GT-P3113 have OTG USB support already built in or do I need to get the cable?

Am thinking of getting a keyboard for my tablet.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [USB Host Diagnostics](http://usbhost.chainfire.eu/?search=P3113) site, YES.
Check the link for the ROMs (Build IDs) that supports OTG.

If your phone has root, you can also check out [USB OTG Helper [root]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.shajul.usbotg&hl=en).